# git rebase: weird stash behaviour

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-stash, git-checkout

I did a `git rebase -i`, selected one commit for edit and git stopped at that commit.

I now try to **checkout** one patch from the **stash** with `git checkout -p stash`.

But this gives me weird old stash contents while `git stash show -p` gives me the expected patches from which I want to checkout one.

What happens here and how can I checkout my hunk from the stash?
Let me know if I shall provide more info.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `git checkout -p 'stash@{42}'`?

Comment: I have only one stash and 'stash' and 'stash@{0}' does not make any difference for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not work directly with stash without the `checkout` command?

---

#### `git stash pop`

> Remove a single stashed state from the stash list and apply it on top of the current working tree stat

---

#### `git stash apply`

> Like pop, but **do not remove** the state from the stash list

---

#### `git stash show`

> Show the changes recorded in the stash as a diff between the stashed state and its original parent

---

In your case you will need to use the `stash@{<revision>}` to execute any stash action you wish to perform.

For example:

```
git stash show -p stash@{0}
```

---

#### View the stash content

```
# display on the stash content
git stash show stash@{1} -u

# checkout the desired commit and choose the right action you want
git checkout -p stash@{0} -p <path to file>
```

[image]

Comment: The commands mentioned by you restore all files and all hunks/patches from the stash. I only want to restore one hunk, hence the `git checkout -p stash` which normally works fine for me.

Comment: restore one hunk - use git stash pop stash@{index} to pull the desired hunk

Comment: no, this restores the whole stash@{0} with all of its hunks, not only one.

Comment: HA, ok now i fully understand what you want :-). Hunk as part of the content of stash, not the whole stash itself

Comment: You can do it in a simple way as you stared: git checkout <sha-1> -p <path to file>

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What's <sha-1>? Does a stash have a hash?

Comment: Added sample code + screenshot. is it what you wanted?

Comment: This is exactly what I've tried and it does not work. `git stash show stash@{0} -p` shows what really is in the stash. `git checkout stash@{0} -p` shows weird older stuff that is not in the stash.

Comment: but did you specify the path to the file after the file name?

Comment: According to pktangyue's answer `git checkout -p stash` is not documented, `git checkout -p` awaits a branch after -p, so stash is not allowed here although it works most of the time and obviously also for you

Comment: there are 2 -p in my sample. one is for patch and second one i added like in git log for path :-)

Comment: Hmmm.... one of the -p seems to suffice, `git checkout -p stash@{0} <filename>` worked fine...

Comment: I will accept this answer, maybe you should edit it for others so that it is clear what the actual solution was.

Comment: It will work as well. im just used to if form the git log.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's look up the document of `git checkout`.

> git checkout [-p|--patch] [] [--] ...
>
> When `<paths>` or --patch are given, git checkout does not switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit). In this case, the -b and --track options are meaningless and giving either of them results in an error. The `<tree-ish>` argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) to update the index for the given paths before updating the working tree.
>
> git checkout with `<paths>` or --patch is used to restore modified or deleted paths to their original contents from the index or replace paths with the contents from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit-ish).

As we can see, the args after `-p` should be a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree), and you passed `stash`. So, how would git handle `stash` is the key point.

You can try `git checkout stash` to see which commit git will goto, and this is what you actually `checkout -p`.

At last, I think you can just use `git stash apply` to make it work.

Comment: You are right. I searched the net and `git checkout -p stash@{0}` is not documented but interestingly works most of the time for me. Obviously not this time. What does work is checkout one file via `git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>`, then commit patches I need via `git add -p`, commit them and restash the rest.